# in redmine run on the correct Ruby interpreter or run as the www-data user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

Some days ago I installed redmine, but lack of reading first install the DB and gave me problems with this. So I remove redmine and try to reinstall it, but i have a new problem:
[image]

redmine already installed correctly, the DB works and apache up service. I already try the bundle install in the project directory but does not give problems, so I think that it is "run on the correct Ruby interpreter or run as the www-data user"

Comment: The exception states bundler cannot find the `rake` gem. Did you run `bundle install` as the message suggested?

Comment: yes, I do @NicNilov

Answer (score 0):

Finally I reinstall the database and redmine. Now its work. the problem was something with the communication with de DB